# Type XXX is not defined in VB

Tags: vba

The following are errors thrown by the code that comes below the error:

> MIL.Html.HtmlDocument is not defined

```
Dim HTMLDoc As MIL.Html.HtmlDocument
```

> MIL.Html.HtmlNodeCollection is not defined

```
Private Sub ParseHTMLDoc(ByVal Nodes As MIL.Html.HtmlNodeCollection)
```

> HtmlNode is not defined

```
For Each Node As MIL.Html.HtmlNode In Nodes
```

Why am I getting these errors

Comment: Your heading says `VB` but you have tagged `C#` why?

Comment: try looking at this or check with the documentation - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6477/MIL-HTML-Parser @MaariR do you know how add referencing also in your `.VB` class file make sure you have the correct `Imports` statement for example `Imports [ aliasname = ] namespace` you also need to make sure that you add that reference manually in the project and set the .dll property for that Dll CopyLocal = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MIL.Html` looks like a third party class library(DLL). Have you imported or added reference of that dll in your project and imported the required namespace to your project? That should solve the problem.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6477/MIL-HTML-Parser

Comment: @MethodMan, Ahh!! had no idea. Good that you pointed.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for response!!!   It works now!!

while running application i am getting error,Actually my call flow should go to if part

For Each rstfile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(s_Deliverables & "\" & msg & "\", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, s_rst_name)
                If rstfile = s_Deliverables & "\" & msg & "\" & s_rst_name 
Then
                    
After that one pop up window come and saying below statement

 A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll